# labeling images to recognize in SURF object detector

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

i am trying to implement a SURF object recognition software, so, i found this code in the internet that implements SURF and it works great (slow, but works), with this i can compare the template image to objects in a scene from my webcam and find them, what i am seeking now is how can i label this template so when the code finds it in the camera feed, the software would return the name of the object appearing., here is the code i have, sorry for no source, could not remember it.

Edit: I have been reading about Bag of Words, but it seems rather complicated to implement, i would like to know if there is a simpler way to do this.

Thank You All.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
Mat object = imread("C:\\teste.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

if (!object.data)
{
    std::cout << "Error reading object " << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

//Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

detector.detect(object, kp_object);

//Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat des_object;

extractor.compute(object, kp_object, des_object);

FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

CvCapture* cap = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
cvSetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
cvSetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);

namedWindow("Good Matches");

std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

//Get the corners from the object
obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0);
obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(object.cols, 0);
obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(object.cols, object.rows);
obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, object.rows);

char key = 'a';
int framecount = 0;
while (key != 27)
{
    Mat frame;
    frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);

    if (framecount < 5)
    {
        framecount++;
        continue;
    }

    Mat des_image, img_matches;
    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
    std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
    std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
    Mat H;
    Mat image;

    cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    detector.detect(image, kp_image);
    extractor.compute(image, kp_image, des_image);

    matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows - 1, (int)matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if ((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int)matches[i].size() <= 2 && (int)matches[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }

    //Draw only "good" matches
    drawMatches(object, kp_object, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
        {
            //Get the keypoints from the good matches
            obj.push_back(kp_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
            scene.push_back(kp_image[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
        }

        H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

        perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

        //Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene image )
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    }

    //Show detected matches
    imshow("Good Matches", img_matches);

    key = waitKey(1);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "how can i label this template" - create a struct or class for each template, give that template a member variable "std::string mLabel;" Set this variable to the label name of the object. When the template is detected, print the mLabel variable to console or render it in the image (cv::putText). Or is your question more like "how to handle multiple templates"??

Comment: Hello Micka, could you show me an example based on the code i got ? i am really new to image processing, so kinda lost, and yes, further on i will need to handle like 10 templates, but for now if i can get 1 to be recognized and have its label displayed would be enough.